# How many different combinations of results are possible in a University course?

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

## How many different combinations of results in assignments are possible in a University course?

I am interesting in calculating the number of unique ways I can finish this course that I am doing. To make things easier, there are no partial marks.

### Here are some conditions:

- There are four assessable tasks

  - Assignment 1: Weighted 10%
  - Assignment 2: Weighted 15%
  - Assignment 3: Weighted 15%
  - Assignment 4: Weighted 60%
- Possible marks for each assessment:

  - Assignment 1: /10
  - Assignment 2: /10
  - Assignment 3: /10
  - Assignment 4: /100

I am a little rusty on my combinations discrete mathematics.

**From an algorithmic point of view, how would you go about solving this?**
What I want to find out is how to iterate through each grade given for each course and return the number of unique combinations that can be achieved in this situation.

I have tried:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < 101; l++) {
                    m++;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(m);
    //out: 134431 
}
```

What I found was that there is 134431 combinations of grades in this situation. But what I want to know also, is how many combinations there are between say the grade of 50-59 (pass) or 60-69(credit). This is what I am confused with.

TL/DR: How many combinations of indiviudal graded assessments can you get in a course? What is the **range** of end of semester marks possible?

*Thank you for your time.*

Comment: What do you mean when you say the possible marks of an assignment are "/10"? Do you mean it's any number between 0 and 10?

Comment: Yep. Any number between 0 and 10.

Comment: What's the formula to get the total points? It is unclear how the weighting works when each assignment has different max points.

Comment: How is it unclear? Weighting systems often work by (mark * weight) no?

Comment: @Ventti using mark * weight you can maximally reach 64 points. This does not seem correct when 60-69 means credit.

Comment: Sorry that this confused you @Henry. I am using the standard weighting system formula. I thought that this was common knowledge. Here is what I did to calculate the weighted mark of Ass 1. Ass1WeightedMark = (my score/ maximum score ) x weight. So, ((9/10)x10) = 9. Sorry but no, the maximum weighted mark is 100, as usual. Sorry again that this was confusing to you.

Answer (score 1):

Just continue with your idea, after you increase your `m` variable, you can calculate the final grade of your combination by using your formula, then from that grade, you can decide put that grade to pass group or credit group.

Mine for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m = 0;
    int pass = 0;
    int credit = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < 101; l++) {
                    m++;
                    float finalGrade = (float) (i * 0.1 + j * 0.15 + k * 0.15 + l * 0.6);
                    if (finalGrade >= 50 && finalGrade < 60) {
                        pass += 1;
                    } else if (finalGrade >= 60 && finalGrade < 70) {
                        credit += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(m);
    System.out.println(pass);
    System.out.println(credit);
    //out: 134431
}
```